# Can't seem to update to sklearn 0.19 with pip?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, anaconda, conda

First I tried to update the package according to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) using the commands below:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

or

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

But the version is still 0.18 in PyCharm. Then I tried to run the update in "Settings--Project Interpreter", but failed with this error:

> InstallError: Error: one or more of the packages already installed
>   depend on 'conda' and should only be installed in the root
>   environment: conda conda-env. These packages need to be removed before
>   conda can proceed.

I'm totally stuck now. Appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: What is the output of `conda install scikit-learn`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use use `virtualenv` in pip and install `scikit-learn` inside the venv. With that solution you dont have to remove sci-kit from conda.

**Install virtualenv using pip3**

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

** Create a virtual environment**

```
virtualenv venv
```

**Active your virtual environment:**

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then you can install now anything you want.

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and was not able to update sklearn. I first removed the scikit-learn package by the below command and then installed scikit-learn in update mode and it got updated successfully.

```
conda remove scikit-learn
```